# Android how to putExtra to an activity from TabHost activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have a little problem with sending an extra from one activity to another. I have let's say `FirstActivity` which starts `TabActivity`, where I have 5 tabs. When I send `putExtra()`, from `FirstActivity`  to `TabActivity`, there is no problem, but I need to send that extra to the `Activity`, which holds first tab of `TabHost`. I'm using this code :

TabActivity.class :

```
int collId = getIntent().getIntExtra("collection_id", 0);
Log.i("Collection ID","Collection ID from SingleCollection.class : "+collId);

intent = new Intent(this, Collection.class);
intent.putExtra("collection_id", collId);

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("collection").setIndicator("Collection",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_collection))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

but it's not really working. I'm not receiving the extra on `Collection.class`.

So my question is how can I send extra to a content of a tab in `TabHost`. Hope you understand me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the child activity you can call `getParent().getIntent()` to obtain `TabActivity`'s intent, so you don't need to put extra in the way you are doing this.

Comment: I tried with `int collId = getParent().getIntent().getExtra("collection_id", 0);` - but it still returns 0. So there is no values for `collection_id`.

Comment: String result = getParent().getIntent().getStringExtra("value");